# Remove Exif data from image in java?

Tags: java, jpeg, exif

What is the simplest way to remove exif data from an image and then move it to another folder? Same location, just in a folder. That way there are original copies.

Thanks.

Comment: Read in the bytes, find what you want to remove, remove it.  I'm sure the jpeg format is available online if you Google for it.  Or, you could use one of several free stand-alone image editors available online.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062959/how-to-remove-image-metadata-from-large-images-without-out-of-memory-in-java

Answer (score 2):

I think an easy way to do this would be to read it as an Image and then write it to the new folder using `ImageIO.read(...)` and `ImageIO.write(...)`. I don't think `Image`s have metadata. If that doesn't work, you could write it as a bmp, then reread it and write it again as a jpeg.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that all your photos are JPEG format, you can use:

```
    try (
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/photo.jpg"));
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/photo_without.jpg"))) {

        new ExifRewriter().removeExifMetadata(is, os);
    }
    catch (IOException | ImageWriteException | ImageReadException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Else, if you have png/bmp/jpg, you need to read/write your image but this method is slower then the first one:

```
    // instead of just using ImageIO.read(stream)
    // https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/197
    try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(stream)) {
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);

        if (!readers.hasNext()) return null;

        ImageReader reader = readers.next();
        reader.setInput(input);
        ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
        BufferedImage img = reader.getImageTypes(0).next().createBufferedImage(reader.getWidth(0), reader.getHeight(0));
        param.setDestination(img);

        try {
            img = reader.read(0, param);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Ignored error reading photo while processing: ", e);
        }

        return img;
    }

    // here you remove the exif
    try (
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/photo.jpg"));
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/photo_without.jpg"))) {

        BufferedImage bi = readPhotoStream(is);
        ImageIO.write(bi, "extensionString", os);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is a binary read of the JPEG file. Search for APP1 markers (Possibly APP2 markers as well for extensions). Copy byte by byte from the source to the destination. When you hit an APP1 (or APP2) marker stop copying and read to the next marker before resuming copying.

The problem that this creates is that your JPEG stream has no meaning. JPEG by itself has no definition of color components. That comes from the Exif (or JFif) markers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Apache common-imaging to remove Exif from JPG/JPEG files.
These examples may be helpful:

[Example of Apache common-imaging](https://github.com/apache/commons-imaging/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/examples/WriteExifMetadataExample.java)

After dealing with Exif, you can new a File to the specific location with `OutputStream` or `byte[]`.

`org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils#copy(byte[], java.io.File)`