How to strip EXIF Metadata from an Image before uploading to S3 without loading the entire file into memory
I have a service that uploads images to AWS S3 using a MultipartFile. These images are later served as public files. There is a security concern: these images might contain sensitive EXIF metadata (e.g., geolocation data) that has to be removed out before making them public.
Problem:
I need to strip the EXIF metadata from these images without loading the entire file into memory, as some of the images could be quite large.
My current approach:
private S3Service.S3UploadedFile uploadImage(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream originalOut = stripMetadata(file.getInputStream());

        final PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try (final PipedOutputStream newOut = new PipedOutputStream(in)) {
                originalOut.writeTo(newOut);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // logging and exception handling should go here
            }
        }).start();

        S3File processedS3File = S3File.builderOf(in, file.getContentType())
                .isPublic(true)
                .contentLength((long) originalOut.size())
                .build();

        return s3Service.upload(bucketName, processedS3File);

    } catch (IOException | ImageWriteException | ImageReadException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("ERR");
    }
}

public static ByteArrayOutputStream stripMetadata(InputStream imageInputStream)
        throws IOException, ImageWriteException, ImageReadException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ExifRewriter exifRewriter = new ExifRewriter();
    exifRewriter.removeExifMetadata(imageInputStream, outputStream);

    return outputStream;
}

The usage of Piped streams is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23874232/6157949
However, in the stripMetadata method, I'm using the Apache Commons Imaging library to remove EXIF metadata. The problem is that it requires an OutputStream, and I'm currently using a ByteArrayOutputStream, which loads the entire image into memory.
What I Need Help With:
I need guidance on how to tweak this approach so that I can strip the EXIF metadata from the image and upload it to S3 without loading the entire file into memory.

Is there a way to stream the image through the metadata stripping process and directly into S3?
Can I use a different approach or library that handles this more efficiently for large files?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

If you only care about JPEG Interchange Format, this format contains segments you  can stream, and optionally skip, while writing. The Exif segment is easily identifiable by using the APP1 marker and "Exif" as identifier string.

@HaraldK , the jpeg method was an example, all these types are supported: "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "tiff".

@catch22 are you sure about that? The docs I found about ExifRewriter state that it is an "Interface for Exif write/update/remove functionality for Jpeg/JFIF images" (emphasis by me). This does not include "png", "gif", "bmp" and "tiff".

@cyberbrain Yes, "Reads a JPEG image, removes all EXIF metadata (by removing the APP1 segment), and writes the result to a stream" is basically the same as I suggest above... The other formats require different ways to remove the problematic meta data. For TIFF, remove the Exif and GPS subdirectories, for PNG, remove any text chunks. For BMP and GIF, I don't know if there are standard ways to include meta data. But beware that meta data can be duplicated in XMP and other segments/chunks/etc too...

@HaraldK is there a way where (your) TwelveMonkeys lib could help in this topic? I wanted to suggest it as an answer but didn't find out quickly how to remove metadata. As you are the guy that wrote that lib maybe you have an idea?

@catch22 you could also find some "inspiration" in answers of https://stackoverflow.com/q/22722652/2846138 (no TwelveMonkeys relation there)

No, not directly. But feel free to look at the source code for inspiration, in classes like JPEGSegmentUtil or JPEGSegmentImageInputStream.

You should simply pass the PipedOutputStream to the call exifRewriter.removeExifMetadata instead of creating a buffer on the heap.
I rewrite your code (untested) to make clear, what I mean:
private S3Service.S3UploadedFile uploadImage(MultipartFile file) {
  try {
    ExifRewriter exifRewriter = new ExifRewriter();
    final PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();

    new Thread(() -> {
      try (final PipedOutputStream newOut = new PipedOutputStream(in)) {
        exifRewriter.removeExifMetadata(file.getInputStream(), newOut);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // logging and exception handling should go here
      }
    }).start();

    S3File processedS3File = S3File.builderOf(in, file.getContentType())
        .isPublic(true)
        .contentLength((long) originalOut.size())
        .build();

    return s3Service.upload(bucketName, processedS3File);
  } catch (IOException | ImageWriteException | ImageReadException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("ERR");
  }
}

